# Fragment transition with shared element similar to activity

Tags: android, fragment, transition

i wan wondering how to achieve such transitions  like (Start an activity with a shared element) provided by the documentation  for  fragments and Navigation component

[https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity][1]

Answer (score 0):

Android framework have already provided shared element transition for fragment. You can start using them by following steps provided in blogs:

- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html
- https://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-2/
- https://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/
- https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb

For fragment, we need to specify the shared transition element while performing the fragment transaction:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .addSharedElement(holder.image, "sharedImage")
        .replace(R.id.container, details)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Hope you find this answer useful.

Comment: this is not what want because i am using the navigation component of jetpack

Comment: @Reham Alatris , I think you need “Transitions in Android Navigation Component” by Sergio Belda https://link.medium.com/ctmzefx6Z5